# Finding a plane containing $(-1,2,1)$, parallel to $\frac{x}{2}=-\frac{y}{3}=-z$, and making a $60^\circ$ angle with $x=y, z=0$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have to find the equation of the plane that passes through $$(-1,2,1),$$ is parallel to the line: $$\frac{x}{2}=-\frac{y}{3}=-z$$ and makes $60^\circ$ angle with $$x=y, z=0$$

I thought that I could take two points from the line and make a vector with them that would be parallel to the plane, but that means I'm just using one of the given conditions and also getting the wrong answer.

Isn't that last condition extra? If I have a point and a parallel line why do I need anything else? And why am I getting the wrong answer? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Could you please help me with this? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the answer?

Comment: There are infinitely many planes parallel to a given line and passing through a given point not on the line.

Comment: @UtkarshJha Honestly I have no idea, I solved this problem as I described and showed it to my professor and he said that it's not the correct answer. :(

Comment: @DavidMitra aha, I see now, thanks

Comment: Here is what I would do: find a second point on the plane using the given point and the parallel line. Find a third point using the given point and the other line. Then find the equation using the three points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last condition is not extra. Parallel to the given line and passing through the given point, one may have infinitely many planes. These can be generated by rotating any one such plane about an axis passing through $(-1,2,1)$ and parallel to the line.

---

Let the normal vector of the desired plane be $(a,b,c)$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. The plane is parallel to $l_1$, so its normal vector is perpendicular to $l_1$, i.e.$$(a,b,c)\cdot(2,-3,-1)=0\iff c=2a-3b$$$l_2$ makes $60^\circ$ with the plane and thus $30^\circ$ with the normal vector. So$$\frac{(a,b,c)\cdot(1,1,0)}{\sqrt2}=\cos(30^\circ)\iff a+b=\sqrt\frac32$$Can you solve these to get the normal vector? Once that is done, the equation of the plane is given by$$((x,y,z)-(-1,2,1))\cdot(a,b,c)=0$$

Comment: I don't understand why the normal vector has to be a unit vector

Comment: @Britanica It doesn't have to be. You may not assume any value for $a^2+b^2+c^2$, but then you will have two equations for three variables$$c=2a-3b\\\frac{(a,b,c)\cdot(1,1,0)}{\sqrt2\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}=\cos(30^\circ)$$which don't admit a unique solution. In this case, you will get $b,c$ in terms of $a$, i.e. $b=k_1a,c=k_2a$, so you can take the normal vector as $(a,b,c)=a(1,k_1,k_2)$ with any non-zero value of $a$ or simply $(1,k_1,k_2)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me this method, I think it worked

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Given two lines $L_1,L_2$ and a point $p_0\in \Pi$ such that

$$
\cases{
L_1\to p = \lambda_1\vec v_1\\
L_2\to p = \lambda_2\vec v_2\\
\Pi\to (p-p_0)\cdot\vec n=0
}
$$

we need

$$
\cases{
\vec n_\cdot \vec v_1 = 0\\
\vec n\cdot\vec v_2 = |\vec n||\vec v_2|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\
|\vec n|= 1
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
\vec n_\cdot \vec v_1 = 0\\
\vec n\cdot\vec v_2 = |\vec v_2|\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\
|\vec n|= 1
}
$$

three equations and three unknowns $\vec n = (n_x,n_y,n_z)$. Here

$$
\cases{
\vec v_1 = (2,-3,-1)\\
\vec v_2 = (1,1,0)
}
$$